# Valgrind to fix memory leaks

Tags: c, parsing, dynamic, memory-leaks, allocation

I have a program which I am reading in a text file of 30,000 numbers that are space separated (5 per line). When I run the program, sometimes it works but other times it doesn't (seg faults) which I believe that means I have memory leaks.

I have the following:

```
int main(int argc, char const *argv[])
{

    char input[256];
    char buffer[30000];
    char **nums = NULL;
    nums = malloc(sizeof(char) * 30000);

    char *token;
    int counter = 0;
    FILE *fp;
    fp = fopen("textfile.txt","r");

    fgets(input,sizeof(input),stdin);

    while (fgets(buffer,sizeof(buffer),fp) != NULL)
    {
        token = strtok(buffer," ");
        nums[counter] = malloc(sizeof(char) * 50);

        while (token != NULL)
        {
            if (strlen(token) > 1)
            {
                strcpy(nums[counter],token);
                counter++;
            }
            token = strtok(NULL," ");
        } 
    }

    for (int x = 0; x < 30000;x++)
    {
        free(nums[x]);
    }

    free(nums);
    fclose(fp);

    return 0;
}
```

I am running valgrind to try to debug but I am having issues reading the output. Could somebody tell me where I am going wrong?

```
==24368== Use of uninitialised value of size 8
==24368==    at 0x4C2588C: strcpy (mc_replace_strmem.c:311)
==24368==    by 0x400820: main (in /home/a.out)
==24368==
==24368== Invalid write of size 1
==24368==    at 0x4C2588C: strcpy (mc_replace_strmem.c:311)
==24368==    by 0x400820: main (in /home/a.out)
==24368==  Address 0x0 is not stack'd, malloc'd or (recently) free'd
==24368==
```

Comment: If you turn on debugging symbols, leaving the compiled code annotated with things like function names, file names, and line numbers, the valgrind output will include file and line numbers. With most compilers its `-g`.

Comment: You're not even allocating memory for `counter`th token, except on first iteration for each line. Also, as these are *numbers*, as you say, I am not sure why would you want to store the *strings* in the array?

Comment: It is unclear whether you are reading 30000 numbers or 6000 lines (5 numbers per line). Why do you need to store the 6000 (30000?) lines, but not the 30000 numbers? Is this an X-Y question? Did you really want a 2-D array `[6000][5]` of those numbers? And why do you throw away the first line, is it column headers?

Comment: I am reading in 6000 lines, but I store each number from that line into the array, which gives me an array of 30,000 numbers @WeatherVane

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you compile with debugging symbols, usually with `-g`, then valgrind will include file and line numbers in its output making it much easier to understand.

---

[@Jean-FrançoisFabre already found one malloc problem](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42680732/14660), your while loop contains more.

```
while (fgets(buffer,sizeof(buffer),fp) != NULL)
{
    token = strtok(buffer," ");
    nums[counter] = malloc(sizeof(char) * 50);
```

You're always allocating memory for `nums[counter]`, but...

```
    while (token != NULL)
    {
        if (strlen(token) > 1)
        {
            strcpy(nums[counter],token);
            counter++;
```

You only sometimes increment `counter`. You're going to leak a lot of memory.

You're also copying `token`, which could be up to 29998 bytes, into `nums[counter]` which is just 50.

```
        }
        token = strtok(NULL," ");
    } 
}
```

---

Instead, allocate `nums[counter]` as it's needed and to the right size.

```
while (fgets(buffer,sizeof(buffer),fp) != NULL)
{
    token = strtok(buffer," ");

    while (token != NULL)
    {
        if (strlen(token) > 1)
        {
            nums[counter] = malloc(sizeof(char) * (strlen(token) + 1));
            strcpy(nums[counter],token);
            counter++;
        }
        token = strtok(NULL," ");
    } 
}
```

Or, if you don't mind using POSIX functions, use [`strdup`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/functions/strdup.html).

```
nums[counter] = strdup(token);
```

And, as others have pointed out in the comments, it's questionable why you're storing numbers as strings. Convert them to numbers immediately with [`strtol`](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/c_standard_library/c_function_strtol.htm) or `strtod` and store that. It's simpler and consumes a lot less memory.

```
long nums[30000];

...

char *end;
nums[counter] = strtol(token, &end, 10);
if( end != '\0' ) {
    fprintf(stderr, "Couldn't understand %s\n", token);
}
```

`end` is a pointer to the spot on `token` where `strtol` stopped parsing. Checking it's a null byte requires that `token` must contain only digits. How strict you want to be with your conversion is up to you.

Answer (score 4):

```
nums = malloc(sizeof(char) * 30000);
```

won't hold 30000 pointers on numbers. The size is too low, should be:

```
nums = malloc(sizeof(char*) * 30000);
```

Aside, instead of doing:

```
token = strtok(buffer," ");
nums[counter] = malloc(sizeof(char) * 50);
```

you should do:

```
token = strtok(buffer," ");
nums[counter] = malloc(strlen(token)+1);
```

so you allocate the right amount of memory for each token (not too much, but not too few), and note that `sizeof(char)` is always 1, so omit it.